# How is this argument getting expanded?

Tags: shell, go, mingw

Consider the following program which I'm running via `MinGW`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(os.Args[1])
}
```

When I run the command `go run test.go /home` it prints `C:/Program Files/Git/home`.

I suspected that the shell might be expanding the relative path. But running `echo /home` prints only `/home`.

What is changing the argument for my golang program?

Comment: but '/home' on widows is not a regular path. it should be absolute `c:\blabla\blabla` or relative `blabla` and `.\blabla`

Answer (score 0):

This must be `MinGW` or the shell that you are running that expands the parameter - to confirm it is not Go specific, try a simple shell script that prints `$0` and `$1` and run it with the `/home` parameter.